# How can I use different fonts in Eclipse editor

Tags: windows, eclipse, fonts

My eclipse editor is only showing 20 fonts. I want to know if it's possible to download some fonts and then to configure Eclipse to use those fonts in an editor.  Specifically, I'd like to use fonts in the Windows font folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to change the font of you eclipse.

In your works area, press RIGHT CLICK > preferences (bottom) > Colors and Fonts > Edit > Choose your font > OK > APPLY